# facebook like button works only on first image

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

i have few photographs in front page of my website way2enjoy.com when a users click on those albums few set of photo opens in facebox style and i have put there facebook like button but i am surprised to see that whatever image you click out of 20 set of images the first click image will show facebook like button and others will not show any like button .for every album there are several photos but i am unable to show like button .

my facebook like code is

```
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=114744998704777";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script><div class="fb-like" data-       send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

any guide/suggestions are welcome

my facebook html code for first image is

`<table class="uiGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td class="vTop hCent"><div><form rel="async" ajaxify="/plugins/like/connect" method="post" action="/plugins/like/connect" onsubmit="return window.Event &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit &amp;&amp; Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" id="u_0_1"><input type="hidden" name="fb_dtsg" value="AQCQ7J4N" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="href" value="http://way2enjoy.com/"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="action" value="like"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="nobootload"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="iframe_referer" value="http://way2enjoy.com/"><input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="ref"><div class="pluginConnectButton"><div class="pluginButton pluginButtonInline pluginConnectButtonDisconnected" title=""><div><button type="submit"><i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like-send sx_like-send_thumb"></i>Like</button></div></div>        <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonPressed pluginButtonInline pluginButtonX pluginConnectButtonConnected hidden_elem" title=""><div><button type="submit"><i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOff img sp_like-send sx_like-send_ch"></i><i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOn img sp_like-send sx_like-send_x" title=""></i>    </button>Like</div></div></div></form></div></td><td class="vTop pls"><table class="uiGrid pluginSend" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id="u_0_2"><tbody><tr><td><div class="pluginButton pluginSendInactive"><div><button type="submit"><i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like-send sx_like-send_send"></i>Send</button></div></div>      <div class="pluginButton pluginButtonPressed pluginSendActive hidden_elem"><div><button type="submit"><i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_like-send sx_like-send_sendp"></i>Send</button></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="pls" style="width: 90%"><div style="padding-left: 19px;" class="uiIconText"><i class="img sp_like-send sx_like-send_fav" style="top: 0px;"></i><span class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_3">You and 9 others like this.</span><span id="u_0_4">9 people like this. Be the first of your friends.     </span></div></td></tr></tbody></table>`

Comment: You need to clean up that code. We're not going to pick through a huge blob of html/FBml like that.

Comment: @MarcB sorry marc . you can check live on way2enjoy.com through firebug

Comment: There's a bit of invalid JavaScript that would certainly muck things up. To get an idea of what errors are appearing, open your page in a developer view (F12 in Chrome) and look in the bottom right corner to see if there's a circle with an X. Clicking on that brings up any JavaScript errors to give you a better shot at determining how to start debugging.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there are just some copy-paste issues. I noticed `data-       send="true"` (which should be `data-send="true"`), along with the `&amp;`'s in the HTML code in the first image.

Comment: @ChrisForrence i have used this code correctly in my file but i dont know how the gap is coming in between data and send my code is     data-send="true"  . as the top url is not changing when i click next photo so that is causing problem.???  i think facebook is considering all pages as same as the top url is same for all images so facebook is showing like button in only first image .whatever sequence you click it will show like button on first cliked image

Comment: Another consideration; did you include the text in your question from the generated code, or from your source? In addition, I noticed that you tagged this question with [php]; is PHP generating this code at all?

Comment: @ChrisForrence that code is in php file so i have used few places /  .under this in above code i have directly copy and pasted from my php file .second set of code are from chrome